# GitHub Actions: make job dependent on at least one other job from an array, but not all of them

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

In my GitHub workflow, I have a finish job that uploads the coverage report to Coveralls once all other jobs are finished.

```yaml
jobs:
  foo: ...
  bar: ...
  finish:
    needs:
      - foo
      - bar
```

If either `foo` or `bar` fails though, or it is skipped (why a job may be skipped is not relevant to this question), the `finish` job won't be run.

Is there a way I could make `finish` run if *at least* one of the jobs provided in the `needs` field is run successfully?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's currently not possible to get `job.status` or `job.conclusion` natively on the workflow to check them on other jobs through conditional.

A **workaround** could be to use `outputs` or `artifacts` to always save each job status.

Here is **an example** using `artifacts` with 3 jobs, where the third job would check the previous 2 jobs status before executing some operation:

```yaml
jobs:
  JOB_01:
    name: Job 01
    . . .
    steps:
      - name: Some steps of job 01
      . . .
      - name: Create file status_job01.txt and write the job status into it
        if: always()
        run: |
          echo ${{ job.status }} > status_job01.txt

      - name: Upload file status_job01.txt as an artifact
        if: always()
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: pass_status_job01
          path: status_job01.txt

  JOB_02:
    name: Job 02
    . . .
    steps:
      - name: Some steps of job 02
      . . .
      - name: Create file status_job02.txt and write the job status into it
        if: always()
        run: |
          echo ${{ job.status }} > status_job02.txt

      - name: Upload file status_job02.txt as an artifact
        if: always()
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: pass_status_job02
          path: status_job02.txt

  JOB_03:
    needs: [JOB_01, JOB_02]
    if: always()
    name: Job 03
    . . .
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact pass_status_job01
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: pass_status_job01

      - name: Download artifact pass_status_job02
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: pass_status_job02

      - name: Set the statuses of Job 01 and Job 02 as output parameters
        id: set_outputs
        run: |
          echo "::set-output name=status_job01::$(<pass_status_job01/status_job01.txt)"
          echo "::set-output name=status_job02::$(<pass_status_job02/status_job02.txt)"

      - name: Show the values of the outputs
        run: |
          # using the syntax steps.<step_id>.outputs.<output_name> to access the output parameters
          echo "status_job01 = ${{ steps.set_outputs.outputs.status_job01 }}"
          echo "status_job02 = ${{ steps.set_outputs.outputs.status_job02 }}"

      - name: Some other steps of job 03
      . . .
```

Where the `other steps of job03` would depend on the outputs results you got from the other jobs, to perform an action or not.

You can find more references about this example on the links below:

- [Get status of multiple jobs in the same workflow](https://github.community/t/get-status-of-multiple-jobs-in-the-same-workflow/17638)
- [How to get status of previous job](https://github.community/t/how-get-the-status-of-previous-jobs/17555)

I also wrote an example here:

- [workflow file](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/16-conditional.yml)
- [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/3311741236?check_suite_focus=true)